# How to update plot window of image using opencv python at certain regular interval?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, plot, imshow

I've set of images which are dynamically being generated by another python script "image_generator.py" at some rate. I want to display these images dynamically. Is there any method so that I can update my image plot with newly generated image from "image_generator.py"?

Comment: Sure, why not just generate them in a loop and display them with `imshow` along the way? Are the images being generated by calling a function? Like `img = image_generator.some_function()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`image_generator.py`**

```
import numpy


def generate(height, width, channels):
    img = numpy.random.rand(height, width, channels)
    img = (255*img).astype(numpy.uint8)
    return img
```

**`example.py`**

```
import cv2
from image_generator import generate

n_images = 20
height = 200
width = 200
channels = 3

for n in range(n_images):
    img = generate(height, width, channels)
    cv2.imshow('Random image', img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(200)
    if k == ord('q') & 0xFF:
        break
```

Note that this is no different than if they were in the same Python file. Once you import from another module, you have access to the functions as they it were sitting inside your Python script.

Comment: Hi Alexander,
Same thing I was looking.I was  trying same way but due to image size too large it was getting hanged. I cropped images and now running smoothly.

Comment: Since Python is an interpreted language, it actually won't progress to display the image until the function is resolved and `img` has a value. I assume your hangup was due to something else other than the images being too large. I just tried for e.g. a `5000x5000x3` image with this script and all worked well (of course the computation to generate the image took a little bit, but not more than a second or so).